# How To Install Blender(bpy) version 3.1.2

Tags: python

I want to install version 3.1.2 of blender(bpy).
I want to do the installation in a pyenv virtual environment.

## install from source code

### What I tried.

#### install from git tab

https://github.com/blender/blender/releases/tag/v3.1.2
I tried to download and build from
When I ran `make update`, I got the following error and could not build.

```
python3 ./build_files/utils/make_update.py
Blender git repository is in detached HEAD state, must be in a branch
make: *** [update] Error 1
```

#### build from git commit

this is what I did

```
git clone git@github.com:blender/blender.git
git reset --hard cc66d1020c3bc9d903ab9ba9f1e186e184262f23 // Change code to v3.1.2
make update // <- This command makes the code the same as the most recent commit.
mkdir b
cd b
cmake ..
make // <- There were no bpy wheel files in the directory generated by the build.
```

I did `make bpy` according to the following url.
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

```
make: *** No rule to make target `bpy'.  Stop.
```

#### install with pip

I got the following error and could not install.

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.18 blender_v3.1.2
pip install future-fstrings
pip install bpy
```

The following error occurs

```
...
      git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
        cmdline: git ls-remote --tags git://git.blender.org/blender.git
        stderr: 'fatal: unable to connect to git.blender.org:
      git.blender.org[0: 82.94.226.104]: errno=Operation timed out
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bpy
  Running setup.py clean for bpy
Failed to build bpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

#### install from official bpy

I can install v3.5 and v3.4 from the following url, but no information about v3.1.2.
https://builder.blender.org/download/bpy/

How can I install bpy in the pyenv virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with "fatal: unable to connect to git.blender.org". Maybe the server is down and we should try later.

I've also tried `pip install git+https://git.blender.org/blender.git` and the answer was:

```
Collecting git+https://git.blender.org/blender.git
  Cloning https://git.blender.org/blender.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-2wvxysf0
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://git.blender.org/blender.git /tmp/pip-req-build-2wvxysf0
  fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
    asked for: https://git.blender.org/blender.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
     redirect: https://projects.blender.org/?service=git-upload-pack
```

Let me know if u got more informations, thank you!